# Using the surface of the unit sphere to calculate $\int_{\mathbb R^3}\chi_{\{x_3>0\}}\chi_{B^c_{1/n}(0)}\exp(-\lvert x\rvert^2)/\lvert x\rvert dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm struggling with finding a proof idea for this integral from an integration theory practice exam.

Suppose
$$f_n:=\frac{\exp(-\lVert x\rVert_2^2)}{\lVert x\rVert_2}\chi_{\{x_3>0\}}(x)\chi_{B^c_{1/n}(0)}(x),$$
show that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^3}f_n d\lambda_3 = \pi\exp(-n^{-2}).$$

**Hint** The surface area of $\mathbb S^2$ is $\omega_3=4\pi$.

Geometrically, we are integrating over the top half-space, excluding a $1/n$ sphere, so naturally, I switched to spherical coordinates. This left me with

$$\int_{\mathbb R^3}f_nd\lambda_3 = \int_{1/n}^\infty\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\pi}r\sin(\theta)\frac1r\exp(-r^2)d\varphi d\theta dr= 2\pi\int_{1/n}^\infty\exp(-r^2)dr,$$
which is not sufficient, even if it it correct.

Because of the hint, I'm surely missing a different perspective on the problem. The only relation I can think of between the surface and the volume is the divergence theorem (Gaussian integral theorem), but I don't see how that could be applied here.

How can this be shown using the hint, and what proof idea is behind it?

Comment: Your Jacobian is incorrect. It should be $r^2\sin\theta$, not $r\sin\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but the determinant you obtain after transformation is $r^2 \sin(\theta)$ leaving you with the expression:

$$2 \pi\int \limits_{1/n}^{\infty} r\cdot exp(-r^2)dr=-2 \pi\frac{\exp(-r^2)}{2}|_{r=1/n}^{r=\infty}.$$
which can be seen using the $u-$substitution $u=r^2.$